# Correct approach to update UI in Android

Tags: android

I'm new to Android stuff. Currently I have someone else code in my hand and I'm trying to understand the functionality. Whoever wrote the code, used Handler and messages in it. For example, if a button is clicked, onClick listener is called which then posts a message to handler. Inside the handler there is a switch case statement which calls different methods based on a data passed in Message what attribute.

My question is, is this a correct approach or we should just call our method directly in the onClick handler.

As i understand, handler should be used to post a message to the main UI thread, from some other thread (worker thread which pulls data from server).

Comment: I would hesitate to remove that until you understand why the original author thought it appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. OnClick should already be running in the UI thread and thus there is no need to use a handler. The only times I have used a Handler is for posting callbacks from an OpenGL or timer/worker thread OR when I need a message to be handled in the future.

*[update] I will add that if the handler is somehow posting to some non-GUI thread then that might make sense under very particular circumstances but the most common case is for code called from onClick to execute in the GUI thread.*

Answer (score 1):

if your method inside button onclick(),is a long running process ,say for a example getting data from server,so it is better to use that method in separate thread.

when the method process is completed ,using handler post message and the proceed further.

Comment: That's what AsyncTask is for. His questions is directly related to the onClick method which *must* be in the GUI thread already